# Bundle install fatal error

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gem

I am migrating my project over to a new machine and I am having trouble running bundle install on the machine I am trying to use.  When I run:

```
bundle install
```

I get this error:

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:294:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:325:in `create_bundle_path'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:51:in `run'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `install'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:78:in `run'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:145:in `install'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have ran gem install bundler and it successfully ran and I have made sure my version of ruby is the same as the version the project was built in  I am running out of ideas and am lost.  Thank you anyone who knows what is going wrong and for taking the time to help me.

```
output of ls -l:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:53 cache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:51 doc
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:53 gems
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:53 specifications
```

cd .. ls -l:

```
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 24 17:51 1.9.1
```

hope this helps!=D

Comment: BTW, I did go to the link recommended in the error and I tried everything they suggested but nothing solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running these commands in a terminal should fix it.

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/
rm -rf .bundle/
rm -rf vendor/cache/
rm -rf Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```

Comment: 2.0.0 is not a dir, I will try and find which dir I have and I ran with sudo but nothing seemed to change after.

Comment: I have 1.9.1, is that an issue?

Comment: Could cause the error, still looks like a simple premission error when creating a directory to me.

Comment: well the sudo schmod775 did not fix it=( it is a new machine so I agree with you, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output of `ls -l` in the `/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/vendor/bundle/ruby` directory?

Comment: Can your user write in the folder `/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/vendor/bundle/ruby`  `sudo chmod 775 /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/vendor/bundle/ruby` it.

Comment: bundle/ruby$ sudo chmod 775
chmod: missing operand after ‘775’

Comment: You need to add the directory. I edited the comment.

Comment: i ran :sudo chmod 775 /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/vendor/bundle/ruby....and there was no output, my ls showed 1.9.1 again and bundle install still doesn't work without sudo

Comment: I edited another solution in my answer.

Comment: running those commands did it^^ sadly there is now a problem with my rake=( going to make a new post for that issue if I cant fix it.  Thanks Pabi! bundler is at least fixed<3